# Should screen reader announce when a dropdown (or combobox) in HTML is expanded

Tags: wai-aria

I am using a very basic HTML Select on a page. This is the code.

```
<label for="favcity">Which is your favorite city?</label>
<select id="favcity" name="select">
    <option value="1">Amsterdam</option>
    <option value="2">Buenos Aires</option>
    <option value="3">Delhi</option>
</select>
```

I see that Screen Reader is announcing "**Collapsed**" when it is collapsed but it is not announcing **Expanded**. Since this is a native HTML Select dropdown, what is the expected behavior for this dropdown by screen readers. Should they announce Expanded when the dropdown is expanded.

Any way to make the screen reader announced Expanded when the Combobox is expanded?

Answer (score 0):

"Expanded" should be announced to indicate the associated content is available to the user.  This is usually done for custom controls (custom droplists, accordions, etc).  For the native HTML Select dropdown, however, this is not needed because the droplist content is available without activating the droplist.  The user can already use the arrow keys to make a selection when the droplist has focus and is not in the dropdown or "expanded" state.  When the dropdown is activated for a Select element, the screen reader will announce "list" or "listbox" to indicate the entire list of options is displayed.  A user can select an item in the list using the keyboard whether or not the list is "expanded", so in this case announcing the  does not offer the visually impaired user